# How to display large image from IPython notebook with scrolling?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can I display a large image with scrollbars inside an IPython notebook output cell? The example below scales down the image to fit into the cell, and `width` does not have any effect.

`from IPython.core.display import Image, display
display(Image('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j22DmsZEv30/maxresdefault.jpg', width=1900))`

Answer (score 4):

Use `unconfined=True` to disable max-width confinement of the image:

`from IPython.core.display import Image, display
display(Image('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/j22DmsZEv30/maxresdefault.jpg', width=1900, unconfined=True))`