# Unable to show web image in IPython notebook using markdown mode

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Based on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370281/how-to-include-image-or-picture-in-jupyter-notebook), I attemped to add my github image to Jupyter notebook, but I always got a question mark as below,

```
![image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370281/how-to-include-image-or-picture-in-jupyter-notebook)
```

[image]

Where has gone wrong?

Comment: try with this link: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicholashub/ForecastNY-2017/master/Images/Computational%20Graph%20of%20f(x).png`

Comment: Doesn't work, either. @eyllanesc

Comment: Try this on jupyter notebook: `![Image on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH4oa.png)` make sure that the cell type is markdown.