# How to import png images Python

Tags: python, image, import, png

I've tried to import a png file in Python 3.6 with Jupyter Notebook with no success.
I've seen some examples that don't work, at least not anymore, i.e.

```
 import os,sys
 import Image
 jpgfile = Image.open("picture.jpg")
```

There is no module called Image that I can install with either:
     conda install Image
or
     pip install Image

Any simple solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370281/how-to-include-image-or-picture-in-jupyter-notebook/32370538#32370538

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Include image or picture in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370281/how-to-include-image-or-picture-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Thanks for the response, Reblochon. However, I'm trying to import images using Python in any IDE, I just happen to be using Jupyter Notebook. I've looked at the links, and they were only for importing images from websites. I'd like to import a saved png file from a folder. And not using Markdown. I'm surprised trying to find the solution is so ambigious :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display an image from file in a Jupyter Notebook as follows:

```
from IPython.display import Image
img = 'fig31_Drosophila.jpg'
Image(url=img)
```

where `img = 'fig31_Drosophila.jpg'` is the path and filename of the image you want. (here, the image is in the same folder as the main script)

alternatively:

```
from IPython.display import Image
img = 'fig31_Drosophila.jpg'
Image(filename=img)
```

You can specify optional args (for `width` and `height` for instance:

```
from IPython.display import Image
img = 'fig31_Drosophila.jpg'
Image(url=img, width=100, height=100)
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated Reblochon! I managed to finally get it to work. I kept getting a broken image output. I had to make sure the file path was correct.   `from IPython.display import Image`,
`img = "C:/Users/Michael/Call_Options_Graphv_1.jpg"`,
`Image(url=img)`