# How to play GIF in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gif

Thanks for help me in advance

I have a gif file say sample.gif what I want to show this GIF file in my `.ipynb` or without opening new window, I have series of `.gif` file and I am creating subplots to display gif's and can't find better solution

I see pyglet but it opens new window to display gif. As I have GIF files only so I think there is no code for provide here

Thanks for helping

EDIT :  Trying below code gives error : `TypeError: Image data of dtype <U10 cannot be converted to float`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow('sample.gif', cmap='gray')
```

---

I found a way to do this using Ipython.display.Image but it do not plots in a subplot it shows all gif one after other in vertical. Can anyone help me on how to apply subplots on Ipython.display.Image

```
with open('sample.gif','rb') as f:
  display(Image(data=f.read(),format="png",width =150,height=150))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I embed a gif in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527868/how-do-i-embed-a-gif-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Thanks for helping i think it's not what I want, I have a pipeline in which I am reading arrays and convert these arrays in gif and then try to play gif as above so I think doing with code is good not markdown command