# Python Notebook Create and Display GIF Without Saving to File

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, animated-gif

In Jupyter Notebook, you can have an image from a Numpy array and show it without having to save it, like so:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

array = np.zeroes((100,100))
img = Image.fromarray(array)
img.show()
```

Is it possible to do the same with a GIF, without having to write to a file? Assuming I already have a list of images I want to show as a GIF within the notebook. Something like this:

```
list_of_images # assume it's loaded beforehand
gif_img = to_gif(list_of_images)
gif_img.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I embed a gif in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527868/how-do-i-embed-a-gif-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: @ksohan That would require either an already existing GIF or for me to save my GIF to file so no. What I want is to be able to display a GIF generated in code without having to save it.