# Embed images in colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Now, I upload my images into google-drive and then use the shareable link to access them in google-colab. I wondering to know is there any way to embed images in google-colab without using google-drive? I mean is there anything like the embedded font in PowerPoint for google-colab?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [How to embed image or picture in jupyter notebook, either from a local machine or from a web resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32370281/10749432)

Comment: @trsvchn Thanks for your reply. I already saw that thread but the solutions provided there not working for colab.