# How to upload ipynb with images in it's markdown cells to google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to upload an `.ipynb` which has images in it's `markdown` cells, but when I upload it to google colab it doesn't show the images. I tried uploading the file solely and with it's '.ipynb_checkpoints' folder and in both cases problem was there.

probably the reason is the way colab saves images in it's cell(image and data in the same place something like this)

[image: colab way of saving images]

but jupyter-notebook on windows saves the image on cell like this

[image: jupyter-notebook on windowsway of saving images]

so how can I upload  an `.ipynb` which has images in it's `markdown` cells from pc to google colab? by the way the answer is not probably in this link [How to embed image or picture in jupyter notebook, either from a local machine or from a web resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370281/how-to-embed-image-or-picture-in-jupyter-notebook-either-from-a-local-machine-o) and also I know when I open the .ipynb in text(notepad) I can access the data (=in the way colab saves the image) but I don't want to copy and paste 100s of images manually.